# Auditing full access permissions on Exchange 2010 without audit being on

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, security

We are currently running Exchange 2010 SP1. I would like to see who has been granted full access or send as permissions on a specific mailbox, the issue is we do not have audit logging turned on this mailbox. We may have an IT employee that is snooping and we would like to stop that...

The question I have is: Is there anywhere else ( system logs, etc. ) where I can track this transaction?

Comment: Are you looking for an audit trail of who granted access, or just a list of people that currently have access?

Comment: @BillSambrone I am looking for an audit trail of who was granted access over the last week

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be kind of a pain (since audit logging is turned off), but you can review Powershell history. Since everything in Exchange 2007/2010/2013 is Powershell based, you can see where someone ran the cmdlet Add-MailboxPermission with the associated parameters. To find the log of Powershell commands, open up eventvwr.msc. Instead of looking in the usual Windows Logs area, look in Applications and Services Logs. You will see a MSExchange Management event source which has all the powershell execution history.

I just checked on my own 2010 environment and added a full mailbox permission, and it pops right up in that log.

Comment: I think this will work marvelously, but just one more question. Is there anyway to filter by the user that I am auditing?